# GlSurface view with XML layout

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I see some questions could be duplicate but i need to ask this because i have other concern about my other code related to the layout that i didn't find in other question.

i have my activity bind with surface view

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glView.setRenderer(this);       
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(glView);
    setContentView(layout);
    glGraphics = new GLGraphics(glView);
    fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(getAssets());
    audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
    input = new AndroidInput(this, glView, 1,1);
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");

}
```

this class actually i took from Mario Zechner's Book, so the OnDrawFrame will be responsible for the looping of update and present state which i like it very much and don't want to recreate it, so i want to use it. the only problem is the book only show how to use the canvas, all the game images will be drawn in the canvas which i don't want to use. i want to use XML layout. set all my images, buttons , etc from there..

I try to setContentView my layout but it will make the onDrawFrame() Stopped , so i can't get my update and present screen code running.

the latest, i tried :

(somewhere when i want to open match screen)

```
    myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.match, layout, false);    
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.leftMargin=0;
    params.topMargin=0;
    layout.addView(myView, params);
```

the onDrawFrame is good, still running but now my layout only displayed 1/4 from top screen, 3/4 below all black.  what caused that ?

How to achieve what i want here, the point is i want glview is still there but only to keep the code (onDrawFrame) Running ,while i want to display full XML layout..   and oh, i also tried to  `glView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` , i got my layout displayed but unfortunately, the onDrawFrame code not running..

Edit: 
tried this recently. but still got 3/4 black screen...
   (on Create)

```
    glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glView.setRenderer(this);           
    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    fL = new FrameLayout(this);
    fL.addView(glView);
    layout.addView(fL);
    setContentView(layout);
```

(somewhere when i want to open match screen)

```
    myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.match, layout, false);
    layout.addView(myView);
```

UPDATED: 
After tracing and searching for hours, now i know the black screen is caused by cleared screen. now the problem narrowed to the "how to make my match view on top of the glsurfaceview?"

Comment: Bear in mind that the Surface part of the GLSurfaceView is a completely separate layer that, by default, sits behind the View UI. You only see the parts of the Surface that show through the View part (which is transparent). Any Views that overlay Surface will obscure it.

Comment: Thank you Sir, after reading your comment several times, i ran some checking from different perspective, and i think it painted all my screen in black color, the 1/4 part which visible turn out coincidently got background color programmatically so it become visible. but what caused it to be black ? i thought it was transparent..

Comment: I think this is back to the old topic , "the glsurfaceview transparency."  , i am gonna search for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on your code, but some have it worked with this code :

```
glView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
glView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

try it and see if you can see your layout on top of the glview now.